# Django Models: Many to Many or One to Many

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

I am trying to figure how to appropriately create the relationship between Order and Ticket models. The user can purchase many tickets, and with it will receive a Ticket ID--but when the User pays the amount of tickets (or ticket ID)--I want it to show the Order ID# with the Ticket ID#. However, I am unsure how to create the relationship between Ticket and Order models. Would I even need Order to be joined with Ticket models? What would you suggest? I tried using Order as many-to-many relationship with ticket, but it didn't seem to work. Suggestions would be helpful.

models.py

````
class User(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    venue=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price=models.DecimalField(default=25.00, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    loop=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchaser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="purchases", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    exp_date=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    cvc=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    buyers=models.ManyToManyField(Ticket, related_name="bought_tickets")-----THIS HAS BEEN DELETED
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ```
````

Comment: Sounds like you're still figuring out, what exactly you're trying to represent in your DB. Once you've found a solid goal the solution might just "click". Questions that seem to unclear to me: Is a bought Ticket always part of an Order? Is a User buying a Ticket, Tickets, Order, or Orders?

Comment: @Bloodmallet: Thank you for the response. I made the sequence where the user is in session and he/she chooses the quantity of ticket/s they want, and later has to pay for it so I figured an Order model would be appropriate to connect with ticket ID? Woud an order model be necessary to connect with Ticket ID ?

Comment: Note you **must not** define your own User model like that. Use the built-in one, which takes care of hashing and checking passwords for you. (It is possible to define your own, if you subclass AbstractUser, but in your case there doesn't seem to be any point.)

Comment: Sounds like you want the User to always obtain an Order. And an Order holds the selected Tickets. One user can have multiple Orders. But an Order can have only one owner User. An Order can have multiple Tickets. A Ticket can have only one Order. Sounds like User doesn't need any special field. Order needs a ForeignKey to User. Ticket needs a ForeignKey to Order. This way all the mentioned restrictions are in place. But keep in mind, that this way an empty Order (Order without tickets) could exist if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 1):

In Order I would suggest a ForeignKey with User as well as a ForeignKey with Ticket. One User may have multiple Tickets and multiple Orders. One Order may have multiple Tickets.

Comment: For multiple tickets per order, you need a FK to Order in Ticket, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for the response cwhisperer. Basically, Order model would come next after User and have instead as "purchaser" as the  Foreign Key. Ticket has a foreign key with Order?

Comment: Ticket has a foreign key with Order? Order with Ticket

Answer (score 0):

There is severall possibilities depending on what you want to do with this Order later on.

If the Order is ticket-based(one order per ticket sold):

1. Ticket and Order need to have a OneToOne relationship: Each ticket
   will lead to only one order, and one order lead back to a ticket.
2. So you can filter all the tickets buy by a specific user and
   retrieve the order like,  and then access for each tickets the order:

Associated code:

```
user_tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(purchaser='a scpecific user_id')
for ticket in user_tickets:
     print(ticket.order.id)
```

If the Order are client based (One order is linked to a User and contains severall tickets) then you should add ForeignKey to User in Order and a ForeignKey to Order in ticket:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    buyer=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="bought_tickets")
    ...
class Ticket(models.Model):
    purchaser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="purchases", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you Ben for the clarification! I add/migrated the above models you described. I also added: order=models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="orders", on_delete=models.PROTECT) to Ticket model. I am trying to have Ticket ID together with Order ID so I stated when a user in request.session submits the ticket options, it'll obtain an order ID behind the scenes till after the user submits an order, I'll show the Order ID. However, I am coming across an error that Name Error: 'order_id' not defined.

Comment: ```def add(request):
    if not 'user_id' in request.session:
        return redirect('/chrisgrafil')
    if request.method!='POST':
        messages.error(request, 'Please select the following options')
        return redirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        Ticket.objects.create(venue=request.POST['venue'], quantity=request.POST['quantity'], loop=request.POST['loop'], purchaser=User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id']), order=Order.objects.get(id=order_id))
        return redirect ('/confirmation')```